# How to access variables in export default?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Want to make come function outside of export default new vue({})
in that function, Can I access some variables in export default?

```
import lang from './lang'
Vue.use(Vuex)

function tr (value) {
  var gLang = this.state.gSettings.lang // <-- how to access state variable?
  return lang[value][gLang]
}

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    gSettings: {
      lang: 'ko',
      goDark: true, 
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    changeSetting (state, payload) {
      return tr(payload.text) // want to use function here
    }
```

Comment: You can `bind()` the function: `return tr.bind(this)(payload.text)` Now `this` inside the function will reference the store object.

Comment: it works like magic! Thank Chris G!!